# Making the free EM field dance

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

Is it possible to build a Turing complete machine out of a source free electromagnetic field (either classical or quantum)?

Comment: Almost certainly not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very likely.

Classically, the superposition principle means that the field can be subdivided into fields generated by different sources that add linearly. So if you have a field $X(t)$ representing a Turing machine, it would be possible to separate it into two fields $X(t)=X_1(t)+X_2(t)$ that evolve independently. Any information processing in $X_1(t)$ will be entirely independent of processing in $X_2(t)$. So if we start with $X_2(0)=0$ ($X(0)=X_1(0)$ is the "Turing-field") and make $X_2(0)$ a field that flips an input bit in the full field, then the evolution of $X_2(t)$ alone needs to produce a field that makes the end state of $X_1(t)+X_2(t)$ correspond to the end state of the program that starts with a flipped bit. But all the other information is in $X_1(0)$ and cannot affect $X_2(t)$: a Turing machine needs to be able to allow different input bits to nonlinearly interact with each other.

Comment: Maybe not on the surface level, but it's also true that the Schrodinger equation obeys the superposition principle. In theory, the whole time evolution of our universe can be described by just a bunch of initial coefficients of energy eigenstates, all of which evolve independently. Yet it certainly looks like my computer, which is a very small part of this universal wavefunction, is doing a computation.

Comment: The reason is because there is a better description of the universal wavefunction besides a long list of independent coefficients, i.e. one which includes the words "computer" and "me", but formally the situation is the same. So while I agree that pure light can't make a practical computer, I wouldn't rule out the existence of complicated configurations of light that are best described in terms of performing a computation.

Comment: @knzhou A computer (classical or quantum) works because the effective Hamiltonian that describes it is time-dependent. A free EM field is described by a Hamiltonian that's time-independent, so you can't implement multiple unitary operators over a fixed time period. And in the absence of interactions it's very difficult to see how a free EM field could coarse-grain to a more interesting effective Hamiltonian, as e.g. the Standard Model Hamiltonian does.